# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Objects$ToStringHelper

Tags: spring, maven, java-8, jersey-2.0

Anyone can you please help how to solve this error i'm using **guava** upgrade version **21.x.**
and i dont want to use version **<= 20.0.**

Answer (score 0):

The Method ToStringHelper was removed in Guava. If you want to use it, you have to change your code and use `com.google.common.base.MoreObjects#toStringHelper(Object)` instead.
If you don't want to (or can't) change your code you have to use the older version of the library.

See JavaDoc for ToStringHelper for example in Guava 18:

> @deprecated Use {@link MoreObjects#toStringHelper(Object)} instead. This method is scheduled for removal in June 2016.

Comment: Yes @TomStroemer you are right but i'm not using toStringHelper to anywhere in my application.   BeanConfig bean= null;
bean.setScan(true);// im gettibg error here. what i posted here. and i'm using swagger with jersey2 configuration.

Comment: and extended ResourceConfig class